# Is the following an unordered selection with or without repetition?

Tags: combinations

**The number of binary strings of length 100 that contain at most two 1s.**

How do we write an expression for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${100\choose 2}+{100\choose 1} + {100\choose 0}$.

You have 100 digits, you choose 2/1/0 of them to be the 1's, the rest being zeroes.

Comment: Thanks! Just want to clarify whether it's a permutation?

Comment: Yes it is- in the sense that the order matters